# How to use function in another function? Python

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to make a game and I am really stuck. The problem is that I cant figur out how to use object oriented programming correctly. The program should launch gameboard function
everytime when the number doesnt equal to arv. It should return the new board with one "O"
less.

```
from random import randint
import time

class Game():    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def beginning(self):
        print("How are you, and why are you playing my game?")
        bla = str(input())
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Hello," + bla + ", I am glad to see you!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Anyways, the you have to guess a number from 1-20")


    def gameboard(self):
        self.__board = ["O","O","O","O","O"]
        print(self.__board)
        self.__board.pop()
        return self.__board   

    def game(self):
        number = randint(1,20)
        print(number)
        x = 1
        arv = input()
        self.arv__ = arv
        while 5 > x:
            if arv == number:
                print("Lucky")
                break
            elif arv != number:
                print ("haha, try again")
                print("one life gone")
                return gameboard()
                print(self.board())
            x += 1

def Main():
    math = Game()
    math.beginning()
    math.game()


Main()
```

Comment: self.__board is the number of lives left? Why do you need it to be a list?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @BrenBarn Please read more carefully... "The problem is that I cant figur out how to use object oriented programming correctly"

Answer (score 0):

Using object-oriented programming when you only ever need one instance of the object tends to overcomplicate the program. I suggest having only one main function.

Nevertheless, I fixed your program. Try to find the changes yourself because I am too lazy to explain them, sorry.

```
from random import randint
import time

class Game():    
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def beginning(self):
        print("How are you, and why are you playing my game?")
        bla = str(input())
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Hello," + bla + ", I am glad to see you!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Anyways, the you have to guess a number from 1-20")
        self.__board = ["O","O","O","O","O"]


    def gameboard(self):
        print(self.__board)
        self.__board.pop()
        return self.__board   

    def game(self):
        number = randint(1,20)
        print(number)
        x = 1
        while 5 > x:
            arv = input()
            self.arv__ = arv
            if arv == number:
                print("Lucky")
                break
            elif arv != number:
                print ("haha, try again")
                print("one life gone")
                self.gameboard()
                print(self.__board)
            x += 1

def Main():
    math = Game()
    math.beginning()
    math.game()


Main()
```

Here is a version of your program that avoids OO and is much more simplified:

```
from random import randint

lives = 5
print("Guess a number from 1 to 20")
number = randint(1, 20)
while (lives > 1 and number != int(input())):
    print("incorrect")
    print("lives: " + "O" * lives)
    lives -= 1

if lives == 0:
    print("The number was actually " + str(number))
else:
    print("You were right")
```